# MySQL - How do I get SUM of a COUNT of a field?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I'm using the following statement and getting almost everything I need. In addition, I'd like to get the SUM of all of the row_total results.

```
    SELECT c.id AS campaign_id, c.amount AS campaign_amount, c.warning_trigger,
COUNT(cc.id) as code_count, DATEDIFF(c.end_date, CURDATE()) as days_remain,
SUM(c.amount) as row_total
FROM campaigns c
JOIN campaign_codes cc
LEFT JOIN partners p on p.id = 4
WHERE c.partner_id = 4 AND cc.status = 0 AND c.id = cc.campaign_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY campaign_amount ASC
```

And here's an example result, with the last column being the column I want to add together:

```
    1 10.00 30 992 24 9920.00
    3 25.00 30 995 290 24875.00
    16 50.00 30 988 335 49400.00
    17 100.00 30 1000 335 100000.00
```

Comment: Do you want both the data currently displayed in you example *and* the sum of the last column's values? If yes: can't you just sum the values up in the application layer?

Comment: Yes, I do want both the data I displayed AND the sum of the last col's values. I could add it together in the controller or view layer, but thought it best suited to the Model.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get the running sum:

```
SELECT  c.id AS campaign_id, c.amount AS campaign_amount, c.warning_trigger,
        COUNT(cc.id) as code_count, DATEDIFF(c.end_date, CURDATE()) as days_remain,
        SUM(c.amount) as row_total, @r := @r + SUM(c.amount) AS running_sum
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars,
        campaign c, …
```

To get the grand total (and all other aggregates) as an additional record:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  c.id AS campaign_id, c.amount AS campaign_amount, c.warning_trigger,
                COUNT(cc.id) as code_count, DATEDIFF(c.end_date, CURDATE()) as days_remain,
                SUM(c.amount) as row_total
        FROM    campaign c, … 
        GROUP BY
                c.id WITH ROLLUP
        ) q
ORDER BY
        campaign_amount ASC
```

To get the total sum in an additional field:

```
        SELECT  c.id AS campaign_id, c.amount AS campaign_amount, c.warning_trigger,
                COUNT(cc.id) as code_count, DATEDIFF(c.end_date, CURDATE()) as days_remain,
                SUM(c.amount) as row_total,
                (
                SELECT  SUM(c.amount)
                FROM    campaign c, …
                -- the same but without the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses. 
                )
        FROM    campaign c, …
        GROUP BY
                c.id
        ORDER BY
                campaign_amount ASC
```

Comment: Quassnoi: this is pretty slick. And it works well if I leave off the ORDER BY, otherwise the ORDER BY throws an error of: Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: @k00k: sure, forgot about that. Just wrap it into a nested query. I'll update the post.

Comment: @Quassnoi: thanks, works well. Though now I'm thinking it would be better if the ROLLUP wasn't an additional record but instead if it was an additional field. This will help on my view layer so I don't display the values in a foreach() loop. Possible?

Comment: After reading a bit more about ROLLUP, I don't think it is possible to put the ROLLUP values in a new field. For now I'm going to use this solution, although the ORDER BY is troublesome as it is hard to really massage it the way I want. For now I'm checking for a NULL value on the view layer.

Comment: @Quassnoi: your last example works perfectly, thanks! Chosen!

Answer (score 4):

Encapsulate your query like:

```
SELECT SUM([row_total]) FROM (
Your query
) Source
```

From the comments below, you could try...

```
Your Query
UNION ALL
SELECT '', '', '', '', '', SUM([row_total]) FROM (
Your query
) Source
```

The union all will allow you to append an additional row to the result set which will give you a 'total row'. You can change the empty fields (the single quotes) to match your data types or assign them special values that will represent your total row.

Comment: Right, but that will only give me the Total and not the other info as well, correct?

Comment: You wan't keep the other information, you want the total of all the information, then there is no way to combine the rest of the rows. If you want to get the sum of every row, just add the SUM(row) over and over.

Wait, do you want a separate row for the total?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the other info in the result too. I would like to have a separate/additional field for the total.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TB.campaign_id, TB.campaign_amount, TB.warning_trigger, TB.code_count,  TB.days_remain, TB.row_total, SUM(TB.row_total) GlobalTotal FROM (SELECT c.id AS campaign_id, c.amount AS campaign_amount, c.warning_trigger,
COUNT(cc.id) as code_count, DATEDIFF(c.end_date, CURDATE()) as days_remain,
SUM(c.amount) as row_total
FROM campaigns c
JOIN campaign_codes cc
LEFT JOIN partners p on p.id = 4
WHERE c.partner_id = 4 AND cc.status = 0 AND c.id = cc.campaign_id
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY campaign_amount ASC) TB
GROUP BY TB.campaign_id, TB.campaign_amount, TB.warning_trigger, TB.code_count,  TB.days_remain, TB.row_total
```

Comment: @Tufo: this will only give me the total though and not all of my example results as well (which I need).

Comment: understood, youre going to do some percentage with both, hun?
i've edited the code, try it now

Comment: That throws an error of:

Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

Comment: Error is gone, but the value of the GlobalTotal is just the same as the value of the row_total.

http://pastie.org/800579